# Как рендерить много информации , которая хранится на сервере? reactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

У меня есть проект на reactJS, я хочу добавить в него раздел БЛОГ. Но тут же возникли вопросы.

Допустим текст статей хранится у меня на сервере.

Сначала я рендерю на клиенте страницу статьи, а потом в момент:

```
 componenDidMount(){
   fetch(/text-statya) ....
   ...
  }
```

в момент когда компонент примотрировался, я подтягиваю текст.

Но вопрос в том как его рендерить?

Ведь тест должен быть разбит на абзацы, заголовки, картинки...

То есть как мне тогда стили к ним применять?

Comment: А вопрос с генерацией текста и его хранением, уже решили?

Comment: Не понял вопрос) Просто на сервере файлы лежать будут

Comment: Суть в том, что надо отталкиваться от того, откуда получается информация и как она храниться

Comment: Не могу сориентироваться( А какие могут быть варианты?

Comment: 1) Пользователи сами ее генирят (посты на сайте) 2) Сами пишете 3) парсите интернет и т.д.  Храните ее сплошным текстом или разбиваете по какому-то смыслу: 1) Заголовок 2) Тело 3) комментарий и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Сохраняете на сервере статьи в виде html разметки

2) Когда вытягиваете текст статьи, делаете setState({...})

3) Вставляете html в ваше DOM дерево

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(/text-statya)
       .then(r => this.setState({text: r}))
       .catch(...)
}

state = {text: ''}

render() {
    return (
         <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.text}} />
    )
}
```

Про dangerouslySetInnerHTML можно почитать [тут](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас почитаю!)
Случайно не знаете что в моём вопросе некорректного, за что его кто то минуснул? :D

Comment: @DmitryFilippov сам не пойму:) но это точно не я:)

Comment: У меня вопрос, а как можно стейтить данные, только когда они полностью прочитаны, а то сейчас у меня в text записывается ReadableStream

Comment: @DmitryFilippov добавьте побольше кода, я не пойму о чем речь:)

Comment: @DmitryFilippov в примере текст выставляется в r, где r-это объект респонза. поменяйте на что-то вроде `.then(r => r.text()).then(r => this.setState({text: r}))`